# javascriptでpromiseの最終結果をスマートに変数へ格納する方法

Tags: javascript, promise

```
aPromise.then(function taskA(value){
  // task A ~何らかの処理~
}).then(function taskB(value){
  // task B
  // taskBのvalueが最終結果です。
  // この最終結果のtaskBのvalueを格納したい。
}).catch(function onRejected(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

例となるコードを書いてみました。
ここのタスクBのvalueを格納したいので試行錯誤したのですが、
結果下に書いたコードになりました。

```
var result = '最終結果が入る変数result';
aPromise.then(function taskA(value){
  // task A ~何らかの処理~
}).then(function taskB(value){
  // task B 
  //ここのvalueを格納したい。
  result = value;
}).catch(function onRejected(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

プログラミング初心者で、自信が無く、
これがスマートな方法なのかが気になって質問しました。

よければ回答をお願いします。

Comment: 格納の仕方自体は他の例が浮かびませんが、そもそもグローバルに保存しておく必要はあるのでしょうか。result はその後どのように使うのですか？

Comment: 格納の方法はそのとおりになると思います。
しかし、それだと`result`が初期化されるタイミングが不定なので、気をつけないとバグの原因になりそうですね。私は Promise そのものを変数に格納して、のちの処理で利用したほうがベターだと考えますが、まぁ、ケースバイケースなのかな...

Answer (score 1):

promise内での計算値(result, AJAXの取得値など)を他モジュール(DOM操作とか)で利用したい、ということだと思います.
グローバル変数の危険さ、タイミング調整の難しさを考慮すると、then内で完結するように書くのが望ましいです.
resultを使った処理中に起こるエラーもcatch内で処理できるようになるので、処理が一箇所にまとまって幸福度が高くなります.

```
// ----otherModule.js----
OtherModule.otherModuleFunction1_UseTaskB_Result = function(result) {
    // がんばってresultを使う処理部分を固めて、モジュール化します
    // taskBの計算値を引数経由で渡すと安全です
};
OtherModule.otherModuleFunction2_UseTaskB_Result = function(result){
    // 適度に分割
}

// ----promiseHandle.js----
aPromise.then(function taskA(resolvedValue){
  // task A ~何らかの処理~
  return doSomething1(resolvedValue);
}).then(function taskB(valueFromTaskA){
  var result = doSomething2(valueFromTaskA);
  OtherModule.otherModuleFunction1_UseTaskB_Result(result);
  OtherModule.otherModuleFunction2_UseTaskB_Result(result);
}).catch(function onRejected(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

複数のPromiseを使う場合は、全員の完了を待ち合わせをするPromise.allも併用するといい感じに実現できると思います.

Answer (score 0):

最近では、`async` `await` を使うのがスマートかと思います。

```js
async function myFunction(aPromise) {
  try {
    // もし taskA() も Promise を返すのだったら、'await taskA(...)'.
    let result = taskB(taskA(await aPromise));
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```